# Dockerized Asp.net Core can't connect to Host's Kafka in WSL

Tags: asp.net, docker, apache-kafka

do you have any idea why my dockerized asp.net core app can't connect to kafka's localhost:9092, but if not dockerized it can successfully connect?

dckerized asp.net core and kafka are both running inside WSL.
e.g.

```
docker run -p 5001:80 --rm my-api
my bootstrap server is: BootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092"
```

error: 
`%3|1573272853.362|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)`

I'f im going to run my asp.net api not inside docker.
It can connect successfully because 127.0.0.1 is pretty straight forward.

Comment: kafka's running inside container?

Comment: Kafka is not running inside container.

Comment: when you use `localhost:9092` it point to localhost of asp.net docker not the host kafka. you should use `hostIp:9092`

Comment: I already did that, but still same issue.

Comment: then why the error show `127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused`, it should not be `127....`

Comment: [thrd:192.168.105.127:9092/bootstrap]: 192.168.105.127:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#192.168.105.127:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 1ms in state CONNECT)

Comment: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1182

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the host address within the container, not localhost, which resolves to the container itself

Then you need to edit the server.properties of Kafka to accept external traffic

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://external.ip:9092
```

Comment: Is kafka not in a container on this scenario?

Comment: It could be, but in this case, no. The point is that you need to expose the interfaces to accept non - local traffic